# How can I force Windows 7 to only use VPN for internet connection?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have set up a VPN connection on a Windows 7 machine using the native Windows VPN adapter.  I am able to successfully connect to the VPN and Windows shows that it has an internet connection, but the wifi connection that I am connected to also maintains it's internet connection.

I need to connect to a website that is blocked on the wifi and am still unable to once I connect to the VPN.  I suspect that my browser is still using the wifi internet to connect to the internet.

I double checked this in the adapter options detail view and they both show an internet connection.  Shouldn't only the VPN show that it has an internet connection? I only want the machine to access the internet through the VPN when I am connected to it.

How can I force Windows to only use the VPN internet connection when I am connected to it?

See Here:

https://www.flickr.com/gp/75933155@N04/dNzJ9r

https://flic.kr/p/27Xbrkw

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an Ethernet connection for VPN? If so, you can just disable Wi-Fi

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying it the wrong way. If you want to access a server/website that is currently blocked by your provider you need to go through a proxy server (one which is not blocked by your provider).

Simply speaking: The VPN only "hides" the data your are sending through the internet to another server from "prying eyes", it does not hide the server you want to connect to.